# error in sending gmail after storing a record in the databse

Tags: laravel, smtp

I have a function to send an email:

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request)
{
    $visit = Visit::create($request->all());
    $host_email = Db::table('users')
        ->where('name', '=', $visit->visitor_host)
        ->pluck('email');

    $to_name = $request->input('visitor_name');
    $data = ['name' => $to_name, "body" => "Test mail"];


    Mail::send('mail', $data, function ($message) use ($to_name, $host_email) {
        $message->to($host_email);
        $message->subject('Visitor coming notification');
        $message->from('cytonnvisitor@gmail.com', 'cytonn');
    });
}
```

this is sent when a record is saved

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $visit = Visit::create($request->all());
    $this->sendEmail($request);

    return response()->json($visit);
}
```

but when i click send i get the error

> [2020-01-25 11:59:26] local.ERROR: Illegal offset type {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Illegal offset type at /home/vagrant/code/front/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMessage.php:297)
>       [stacktrace]

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, why are you creating 2 visits?

Comment: am using 5.8  because when i  dont put on the function sendmail i get the error Undefined variable '$visit'